# Understanding UnsafeRawPointer in objc_setAssociatedObject

Tags: objective-c, swift, unsafe, unsafe-pointers, associated-object

I'd like to set `n` number of associated objects to an object in Swift

My understanding is the usual pattern for the `UnsafeRawPointer` reference is like this...

```
static var reference = "someRef"

public func add(to myObject: AnyObject) {
    let adding = ThingToAdd()        
    objc_setAssociatedObject(myObject, &reference, adding, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}
```

but this wouldn't work for `n` number of calls to `add(to:)`

Similarly, the below code works fine if I only call it once per `myObject`.. However, if I add another associated object in the same way... it replaces the first `ThingToAdd` with the second. Building a unique string inline does not work. On the simulator it's fine but on a device it's not.

```
public func add(to myObject: AnyObject) {

    let adding = ThingToAdd()
    var reference = "objectref\(UUID().uuidString)".replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")

    objc_setAssociatedObject(myObject, reference, adding, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

}
```

I understand that this is incorrect, however I don't know how to create `n` number of `UnsafeRawPointers` in order to store the associated objects with unique references.

Any help / explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `reference` to the `key: UnsafeRawPointer` argument of `objc_setAssociatedObject` passes the *address* of the variable storage to that function.

Global variables and static member variables (and only those) are guaranteed to have a fixed address.

In your first version, the second and all subsequent calls to `objc_setAssociatedObject` with the same key replace a previous association.

In your second version, the address of a local variable is passed as key. That address may or may not be the same on subsequent calls. Note that the contents of the string is irrelevant, the key is just a pointer, i.e. the address of that variable.

If you need to associate a *variable number* of values with a given object then I would suggest to associate a single `NSMutableArray` (or `NSMutableDictionary`) and add the values to that array or dictionary.

Comment: Yeah makes sense. I was still hopeful there would be a way to add n number dynamically, but you're right, it could easily be solved by an array or a dictionary.